# Facebook Send Dialog identify whether send or cancel has been clicked

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the Facebook Send Dialog to send messages to friends. As documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/ and am using a link like the one in Facebook's example:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=123050457758183&name=People%20Argue%20Just%20to%20Win&link=http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html&redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/response`

On the page I have specified as the `redirect_uri` I am displaying text saying: "Your message has been sent".  However I've realised that you see this page even if you've clicked cancel in the Facebook dialog.

Is there any way to determine whether *save* or *cancel* has been clicked?

**Update:** I've found a workaround using the FB.ui method which solves the immediate issue I was having.  *I would still be interested to know if anyone has a better solution using a Send Dialog link like the one above.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a work around by using Facebook's Javascript SDK's FB.ui method.

```
      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html,
          display: 'popup'
          });
```

N.B. display must be set to popup for this to work!

As it does not require a `redirect_uri`, the issue of knowing whether save or cancel has been clicked is not an issue.  If however you do wish to know this, you can access a response object:

```
      FB.ui({
          method: 'send',
          name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
          link: 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/06/15/arts/people-argue-just-to-win-scholars-assert.html,
          display: 'popup'
          },
          function(response) {
              if (response){
                  // save has been clicked
              } else {
                  // cancel has been clicked
              }
          });
```

Comment: the response object doesn't provide any information about if the user continued to send or cancelled out. I'm stuck at the same place.

Comment: @AbhinavGujjar - see Pontus Hymer's answer below.  I'll update mine to include his findings.

Comment: well. at least for the 'share' action this does not seem to apply. it returns a non-null object for both cancel and post. I've started a different thread over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23884573/how-to-detect-user-cancelled-share-when-using-fb-ui

Comment: I think that since the "Share" operation is one that can be undone (by the user simply deleting the post), the api may intentionally not be offering the status differentiator between cancel and Share.

Other explanation is that they did this to prevent other sites using this as a gateway to other functionality and forcing people to post something as a status update.

Comment: @Andy, could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66654709/facebook-sdk-send-method-in-reactjs

Answer (score 5):

Small complement to Andy's response:
the response-object does not give much info about what has been sent, actually (returns [] in console), but the mere EXISTENCE of the reponse object indicates the "SEND" button has been pressed

```
FB.ui(obj, function (param) {
if (param) {
// The "SEND" button has been pressed
}
else{
// The "Cancel" button has been pressed
}
```

Comment: Anyone know how errors are reported here?  For instance, if the user does click "Share", but an error is encountered - such as insufficient facebook permissions, or a network timeout, how is the response object populated?