# How to detect user cancelled share when using fb.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm using the documentation provided over [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) with the following code. The share dialog comes up correctly. The problem is that I'm not able to differentiate between "Cancel" and "Post" actions that the user takes on the dialog. I'd imagine this would be a part of the response.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){
    if (response && !response.error_code) {
        console.log(response);
    } else {
        alert('Error while posting.');
    }
});
```

edit: output from the console isn't doesn't provide any way of knowing

```
Cancel - Object {e2e: "{"submit_0":1401181811121}"} 
Post - Object {e2e: "{"submit_0":1401181815112}"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tested this, and apparently there's some info in the `response` object you could use to determine if the dialog was cancelled.

Code

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
}, function(response){
    if (response && !response.error_code) {
        console.log("OK: "+JSON.stringify(response));
    } else {
        console.log("Not OK: "+JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

Output upon cancellation:

```
{error_code: 4201, error_message: "User+canceled+the+Dialog+flow", e2e: "{"submit_0":1401188820613}"}
```

So, I guess you could check for cancellaction like this:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share',
    href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
}, function(response){
    if (response && !response.error_code) {
        console.log("OK: "+JSON.stringify(response));
    } else if (response && response.error_code === 4201) { //Cancelled
        console.log("User cancelled: "+decodeURIComponent(response.error_message));
    } else {
        console.log("Not OK: "+JSON.stringify(response));
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, `FB.Events.subscribe()` doesn't offer an Event for the Cancallation of this dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.0

Comment: that's what i would have thought, but in both cases response is not null. I've edited my answer to show the response object as output to the console

Comment: Hmmm, the output of the cancelled "version" looks strange. One could think that an object was create anyway. Could you please add the code snipped how you create to output to the console?

Comment: I have a statement "console.log" in the code snippet above.

Comment: I read that, but the `console.log` is only triggered if there is no `error_code` in the `response`, so this shouldn't have produced your output.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. There is no error code when the user cancels. Have created a plnkr for this - http://embed.plnkr.co/4sd0kRv3anqZt5YvPHGY/preview

Comment: Works for me in my example in Chrome: http://run.plnkr.co/plunks/M4H2FUsH1wBYv5VS4SjU/

Comment: It appears that this status is available only when the user is logged into the app. I'm not sure if this is a bug or by design. Will update over here when I've understood in more detail.

Comment: I guess with "logged into the app" you mean the user gave permissions to the app. That's correct I think. But you can't post on a user's wall without having the appropriate `publish_actions` permission, so the user needs to authorize the app anyway

Answer (score 2):

This is intentionally so as to dissuade developers from using posting as a gating mechanism. It should be up to the person to choose whether to post or not, it should not be a requirement of the app.

Comment: I also suspected that this might be the case. I haven't been able to get Tobi's answer working yet.

Answer (score 2):

Use "feed" method instead of "share" so that it doesn't require app permission to get the response.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    caption: 'My Caption',
    link: 'http://www.google.com/'
}, function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
        alert('Thank you for sharing!');                
    } else {
        alert('You have cancelled the share.');
    }
});
```

Comment: if (response && response.post_id) is not working in chrome when cancel button clicks.

Comment: The parameter post_id is in a 6 month deprecation window for use without publish_actions permission. Beginning October 12, 2016

Answer (score 1):

I also have a problem with the response function, I'm currently coding and trying to use fb.UI

```
    return FB.ui({
      method: 'share',
      href: this.shareUrl,
      hashtag: "myHashTag",
      quote: "myQuote"
    }, function(res) {
      console.log("res = ", res);
      console.log("res? = ", res != null);
      return App.vent.trigger("FBShareView:cancelled");
    });
```

I'm finding that on a successful share, res is an empty array and res != null is true

I'm finding that for the cancel scenario, res is undefined.

I expected to see res as an object with an error_message as described here:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Could you tell me what may be going wrong please?